# Android org.json.JSONObject returns null in unit tests

Tags: android, json, junit, kotlin

I have a problem connected with parsing JSON while testing functionality using JUnit. I want to test my parsing logic. While I am executing test case I receive an error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getString in org.json.JSONObject not mocked`

I have read that there is a need to provide additional dependency to tests because of `org.json` is provided with Android SDK, so I have put into gradle:

`testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180130'`

Unfortunately, this has no effect. Error occurs when I execute function `getString()` on JSON object:

`json.getString(JSON_TYPE)`

Have anyone had a similar problem and know how to deal with it?

//EDIT

here is the function (shortened form) that is responsible for parsing and causes the problem:

```
fun parse(jsonString: String) {
   val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
   val type = json.getString(JSON_TYPE) //here occurs an error
   val id = json.getString(JSON_ID)
}
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your test case?

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert please take a look at my edited post

Comment: are you using `robolectric.org` ? If so, annotating your test class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` should mock JSONObject correctly.

Comment: I am not using it, and I hope that I can get rid of the problem without using `Robolectric`. If not I will definitely use it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the following to the build.gradle:
The code below works for me, When I need to parse Json in Test

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
//...
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
}
```

Comment: NOTE: `org.json:json:20180813` library doesn't work exactly the same as the Android implementation. for example when treating numbers as strings: `new JSONObject("{\"foo\":123.45}").getString("foo")` will throw an exception, but on Android it returns "123.45". This caused my tests to fail even though the code worked...

Answer (score 2):

Just combining all the answers above

```
android{
.
.
.
testOptions {
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}
```

As well as adding

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20160810'
```

in your build.gradle file shall solve your problems

Comment: `unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true` is not required to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Please see the ["Error: method not mocked"](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) section of the developer's guide:

> If you run a test that calls an API from the Android SDK that you do
>   not mock, you'll receive an error that says this method is not mocked.
>   That's because the android.jar file used to run unit tests does not
>   contain any actual code (those APIs are provided only by the Android
>   system image on a device).
>
> Instead, all methods throw exceptions by default. This is to make sure
>   your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on any
>   particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not
>   explicitly mocked, such as with Mockito).

`JSONObject` is not a great way to serialize/deserialize JSON - there are better options like Gson and Moshi. However, if you must use it and you need to unit test you can install Robolectric which provides test doubles called "shadows" of Android classes like `JSONObject`.

Comment: After a while, it turned out that adding `testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180130'` my tests started do work. For sure in the future, I will change my implementation from `org.json` to `GSON`. Thanks for the help.